# Link from popup doesn't work properly

Tags: html, anchor

I have a popup containing a link to view Ts & cs at the foot of the home page. I added this code

```
I have read the <a data-scroll href="home.html#terms" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a>
```

It opens the right page but does not jump (or scroll) to the correct position on the page. But if I then press enter in the address bar it will go to the right spot. Any way to fix this please?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://html.com/javascript/popup-windows/

Answer (score 0):

In my example it works fine, but leave the data-scroll out then:

```
<a href="home.html#terms" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a>
```

Comment: I tried with and without data-scroll. It makes no difference. My page is at http://www.bloemfonteinspca.co.za/home.html. Click DONATE to open the pop up, and then click on terms and conditions. It loads the page but ignores the #terms anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, its nothing wrong with your code.try to provide working sample if possible.
Something like this works fine

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"><a data-scroll href="#bottom">go to bottom</a></div>
<div id="bottom"><a data-scroll href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/40574219/5929494" target="_self">Terms & Conditions (to SO)</a></br> i use *target= _self* in this case. but you can still using *target=_blank*</div>
```